# Working with long let expressions in Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure

I run into this scenario pretty often and was wondering if there's an easy solution.  Say I've got a Clojure source file that has a `let` expression like the following:

```
(let [a (...)
      b (...)
      c (...)
      d (...)
      e (...)
      f (...)
      g (...)
      h (...)] 
  (...))
```

where each value is dependent on some of the values above.

Then when I want to manually work with say the expression that defines `h` in the REPL (assume that at least one of the inputs is some huge map JSON response or something that would be even more of a pain to type out manually), then I find myself manually doing

```
(def a (...))
(def b (...))
(def c (...))
(def d (...))
(def e (...))
(def f (...))
(def g (...))
```

before I can even start trying to mess with `h`.

So usually that means typing `(def )` into the REPL, then moving my mouse, copy the `a (...)` from the `let` expression, pasting back into the `(def )` then hitting enter, and then going back and doing the same thing for `b` and so on.

Is there a quicker way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also write a macro which takes the bindings of a `let` form and turns it into a sequence of `def` forms.

```
(defmacro letdef [bindings]
  (apply list `do (for [[s expr] (partition-all 2 bindings)]
                    `(def ~s ~expr))))

(letdef [a 1
         b 2
         c 3
         etc (+ a b c)])

(println etc) ;=> 6
```

Comment: Great! Why wouldn't this be part of core? Seems like it should be a common need. Isn't it? Or are long `let`s not Clojuresque? If not, what is a more idiomatic way of defining lots of values?

Comment: IOW I find myself needing this *all the time*, and given I don't think I'm doing anything unusual I'd think others would need it too. So am wondering, given this macro is not in core, is there something fundamental that I'm just not understanding about how to program in clojure?

Comment: Long lets (> 5 bindings) are uncommon but kosher afaik. I've always worked around this sort of thing using ad-hoc `def`s when doing repl-driven development. I tend to avoid the need for it most of the time by a mix of debugging (Cursive is awesome) and thoughtful problem decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack that might work for you:

```
(let [a (...)
      b (...)
      c (...)
      d (...)
      e (...)
      f (...)
      g (...)
      h (...)
      _ (def h' h)] 
  (...))
```

Obviously you'd never want something like this is checked in code, but for hacking things in the REPL it might suffice.